# Match URLs with HTaccess for some strings but not others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a while now. I've succeeded in referring all URLs from a two digit subfolder (ie the language folders) back to the main site. So I've got these a URL like this:

`http://www.mysite.com/de/index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1...etc`

going to

`http://www.mysite.com/index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1...etc`

using this HTacess line:

`RedirectMatch 301 /../(.*)index.php(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1`

This was fine until recently when I've added an affiliate system which has urls starting with index.php and I'd like to make this component exempt from the rewrite rule.

In Summary, I'd like to be able to create a rule or match that matched URLs like :

`http://www.mysite.com/de/index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1...etc`

but didn't match URLs like:

`http://www.mysite.com/de/index.php?option=com_affiliate`
and
`http://www.mysite.com/de/index.php?option=com_affiliate&sec=banners`

Thanks for your time in reading this. Ant.

Here is a link to my HTaccess file: http://www.seed-city.com/htaccess.txt

Answer (score 0):

Using `mod_rewrite` you can do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !option=com_affiliate
RewriteRule [a-zA-Z]{2}\/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I added it into my htaccess file but the only thing I could see as a result was my pictures did not load. I've edited my question to show my full htaccess file. If I understand your rule correctly, would that not just remove the lang folder for all queries apart from option=com_affiliate, is there a way to say redirect `index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1...etc` but not `http://www.mysite.com/de/index.php?option=com_affiliate&sec=banners`   Is order important in placement of your rule? Thanks again.

Comment: @clmarquart You can see my htaccess file above? Is placement important for it to work? Thx.

Comment: Order definitely matters.  What I provided will redirect all non `com_affiliate` links thats are in a language folder (i.e `/de/`) to the root.  From your first comment, are you saying that you your URLs don't have the standard `?` for the querystring? and they start with the `&` after index.php?

Comment: @clmarquart Hi there, I've confused the issue now. The URL is always in this format: `http://www.seed-city.com/de/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1_seed_type_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_ etc` It only changes to an ampersand upon my current redirect. I want the opposite of what you're saying. I want the com_affiliate links not going to root and the com_virtuemart links going to root. I want to be able to translate the affiliate section but not the com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse etc. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: @clmarquart, I see what you're saying all non-com_affiliate links so it's not the opposite as I said. The problem is I have a great deal of translated links that are fine I just don't want it translating in the event of a URL that starts with `http://www.seed-city.com/de/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&produc­t_type_id=1&product_type_1_seed_type_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_ etc` I originally made it so with the line:   `RedirectMatch 301 /../(.*)index.php(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1` but this is too broad and is now causing me problems.

Comment: @clmarquart In fact I think I could really simplify my problem down to I want to match any URL starting with `http://www.seed-city.com/de/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&produc­­t_type_id=1` in a way that matches more of the URL than just the index.php part rather than the solution I came too previously: `RedirectMatch 301 /../(.*)index.php(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1` which matches anything that includes an index.php. Thanks again.